# netbook slow on ubuntu (and win 7). Tips and tricks for speeding up

Tags: performance, ubuntu-netbook

My computer just broke down so I got a new one on second hand because I need one in the mean time while it's on repair. I got a 10" Dell Inspiron mini 1012.
However, it's slow. Really slow. Usually when I open like 10 tabs with just text in chrome it freezes and becomes unresponsive.

The computer was completely wiped and came with a brand new Windows 7 starter edition freshly installed. I tried installing Ubuntu 12.10 on it and it was a little bit faster but it's still slow and becomes unresponsive a lot of times.
I'm thinking of buying some extra RAM for it (updating from 1 g to 2 g). However I'm wondering if this would help. Is it probable that it is the low ram that makes it slow or could it be that it is something else, like the hard drive being worn out because it is second hand?

Are there any Ubuntu tweaks I can do that can make the installation lighter?  Or if not, any other Linux distro that might be good for my particular computer. I know that Ubuntu had a netbook edition before but from what I understand the two merged.

I sort of can't get my head around why it's so slow because my other laptop had like 2 g of RAM and a similar speed on the processor and I have no problem running seven YouTube videos simultaneously while doing other stuff. With this, however, running only 1 YouTube video often lags.

What do you think?  Is the extra gig of RAM worth it or will it still be slow on account of it being a netbook and being cheap?

Specs:

- *Chipset*: Intel® Atom NM10 Express
- *CPU speed*: 1.66 GHz
- *RAM memory*: 1 GB
- *Wireless*: Dell™ Wireless 1397 802.11g Half mini-card
- *Bluetooth*: Dell Wireless 365 Bluetooth Internal (2.1) mini-card
- Integrated network connector 10/100 LAN (RJ45)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 is actually really slow. If you really really like unity interface i would recommend you to first try 12.04 version, cause is faster than 12.10, and it's a long time support. It also has a 2D unity interface which is better for old computers. If it's still slow using that, or if you don't like unity that much, i would strongly recommend to use Lubuntu 12.10. It's waaaay faster, everything loads almost immediately. I'm running a netbook with 1gb RAM and lubuntu, and it works faster than a laptop with 4gb RAM running ubuntu.